# Spring data repositories get unloaded after 5 minutes

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, sybase

I'm debugging a spring application, which "loses" it's Entities/Repositories after ~5 Minutes.

`application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.jpa.database=SYBASE
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sybase:Tds:database-host:2638/R4Sybase
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.maxLifeTime=60000

logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=DEBUG

spring.jpa.open-in-view=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
```

Example repository:

```
public interface EstateRepository extends CrudRepository<Estate, Integer> {
/* ... nothing special ... */
}
```

After startup/initialization, available entities are listed under `/`:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "estates" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/choices/estates"
    },
    /* ... more entities ... */
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/choices/profile"
    }
}
```

However, after ~5 Minutes, the response for `/`changes to

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/choices/profile"
    }
  }
}
```

It seems like all entities/repos are unloaded, there aren't any exceptions in the catalina log, no timeouts, no database errors at all. Reloading the app in tomcat fixes things for another 5 minutes.

I've tried fiddling with connection pool settings, switching to a Tomcat connection pool but to no avail.

Is there some kind of keep-alive setting? Is this a garbage collection issue?

Comment: you think this could have anything to do with it `spring.datasource.maxLifeTime=60000`? It is milliseconds = 60seconds

Comment: It might. I put it in after the trouble started. I had it on default before (not configured). I wanted the pool to recycle connections after a minute of idle time to always have "fresh" connections

Comment: I agree with J Asgarov, maxLifeTime could be the culprit, what do you mean fresh connections, mongo drivers handle connections and reconnects or creates more new connections when needed.

Comment: What I did try was upgrading my spring dependencies from v 2.2.6 to 2.3.3. This *seem* to have fixed it in combination with my Tomcat 9.0.24... But I still don't understand why this worked in the first place.